# Fixed divs with responsive gutters / margins between them

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a parent fluid div (`100%` width) with 5 fixed width divs within it (`50px` each). I want the margin / gutter between the fixed divs to be equal, and contract when the width of the parent fluid div is reduced.

Unfortunately, the divs are eventually pushed down even though there is room for contraction within the margin / gutter. Is there a way to achieve this? It is **important** that the 5 child divs have fixed widths.

This is what I want: 
[image]

This is what I **don't** want: 
[image]

Here's what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/D6YxF/

```
<div class="fluid-parent">
    <div class="fixed-div">div 1</div>
    <div class="fixed-div">div 2</div>
    <div class="fixed-div">div 3</div>
    <div class="fixed-div">div 4</div>
    <div class="fixed-div fixed-div-last">div 5</div>    
</div>

.fluid-parent {
    background-color: rgb(187, 187, 187);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.fixed-div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 102, 255);
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.fixed-div:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;    
}
```

Comment: which browsers do you need to support? IE9/8/7 ?

Comment: @fabrizio-calderan IE8+ if possible, but I'd like to see any solutions for CSS3 browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On modern browser you may use `display: flex` like so:

> **Example fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/gy8GD/1/

---

**CSS**

```
.fluid-parent {
    background-color: rgb(187, 187, 187);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.fixed-div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    flex-shrink:0;
    margin: 0 auto 0 0;
    background-color: rgb(0, 102, 255);
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

---

Unfortunately display: flex is not widely supported yet especially on `IE<10`. Another solution with a wider cross-browser compatibility (`IE9+`) is cheating with pseudoelements and `calc()`

> **Example fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/uCqK5/2/

**CSS**

```
.fluid-parent {
    background-color: rgb(187, 187, 187);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.fixed-div {
    width: 20%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 102, 255);
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.fixed-div:after {
    content: "";
    float: right;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 50px);    
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 50px);    
    width: calc(100% - 50px);    
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(187,187,187);
}
```

Basically every div is `1/5`<sup>th</sup> of the parent width, but an `:after` pseudoelement is placed on their right side, filled with the parent `background-color` and their width is defined as `100% - 50px`.

Honestly I didn't find yet an approach for `IE8` but I'll put my head on it

Answer (score 0):

What if you try changing fixed-div width to 5%? When you are making a responsive design I would advice you to work with percentages as much as possible.

Like this:

```
.fixed-div {
width: 5%;
height: 50px;
background-color: rgb(0, 102, 255);
float: left;
margin-right: 15%;
text-align: center;
color: white;
font-family: Arial;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D6YxF/1/

Comment: I need the divs to have a fixed width.

Comment: Ah sorry my mistake. Have you thought about using media queries? So you can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/D6YxF/3/

Comment: Yea I thought about it, but I would have to adjust it for every few pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/D6YxF/5/

**HTML**

```
<div class="fluid-parent">
  <div id='div1' class="fixed-div">div 1</div>
  <div id='div2' class="fixed-div">div 2</div>
  <div id='div3' class="fixed-div">div 3</div>
  <div id='div4' class="fixed-div">div 4</div>
  <div id='div5' class="fixed-div fixed-div-last">div 5</div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fluid-parent {
   background-color: rgb(187, 187, 187);
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
}

.fixed-div {
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 102, 255);
  text-align: center;
  float:left;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
 }
 #div1{
   left:0%;
 }
 #div2{
   left:15%;
 }
 #div3{
   left:30%;
 }
 #div4{
   left:45%;
 }
 #div5{
  left:60%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="fluid-parent">
<div class="fixed-div">div 1</div>
<div class="fixed-div">div 2</div>
<div class="fixed-div">div 3</div>
<div class="fixed-div">div 4</div>
<div class="fixed-div fixed-div-last">div 5</div>    
</div>
.fluid-parent {
 background-color: rgb(187, 187, 187);
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 position:relative;
 }

 .fixed-div {
   width: 20%;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: rgb(0, 102, 255);
   float: left;
   margin-right: 15%;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
   font-family: Arial;
  }
```